# How to make crenel from a cube?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Here is the base structure.
[image: The base structure]

Using subdivide I could achieve something below, but it's not what I want. How could I subdivide the hollow rectangle from the inner side? I need the the surface between crenels to be parallel
[image]

Here is the reference Image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the knife tool to cut these orthogonal edges (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

You end up with this, don't forget to remove all the oblique edges:

[image]

Create some loopcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

Extrude up the crenels:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I have a solution assuming your cube is oriented perfectly to the X and Y axes (as I'm sure it will be)

From what you've got here, select one of your inner-facing edges and then scale it by 0 along either the X or Y axis, depending on which way it's facing.

I'm not able to get into Blender right now so cannot show a screenshot, but the easiest way is to select an edge, then press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, or <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>.